# Unity does not create a project folder

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm creating a project in Unity Hub, but when I try to open it, it throws an error. This project simply does not exist in the project folder (because of the error and the error). Several times I checked the correctness of the path.
I've reinstalled Unity several times but nothing has changed.

MacOS, path is /Users/Apple/unity_projects. It exists and is listed in the settings.

Comment: What OS. What path. Does the project path on hub exist. So you have permissions to it.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled Unity again and it worked. The only possible problem is a lack of memory, because I did the same thing as before